# Is here any opportunity to update component by the widgetVar value from the bean?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

Problem that I have a `p:dataTable` with, for example `widgetVar="dataTableVar"`. And I need to update this table from bean. I know that simplest way it update it by id, but in my case I need update `p:dataTable` exactly by widgetVar. I succeeded to do it via:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("@widgetVar(dataTableVar)");
```

It works. But Is there other way? Or it is ok?

Comment: as long as it works this way, what exacltly is your problem?!

Comment: It is a workaround. I want to know direct, native method. This way as I think not proper....